# Pocket Hardware Synth vs Raspberry PI

Tags: synthesizer

I've recently been looking into buying a pocket sized synth to make my midi keyboard 'portable'.

I was suprised at the cost of them ([link](http://www.factmag.com/2015/03/28/best-affordable-small-hackable-open-source-off-the-wall-synthesizers/8/)) for what you actually get. What is the difference between using one of these guys vs buying a Raspberry Pi for around £25 and installing one of any number of free software synthesisers to essentially convert it into a pocket sized synth?